# When does Spring clear the baggage context?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a code like below where I am observing that `id` is empty. But if I remove the `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` ,I can get the `id` which is set in the request processing flow.

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CollectionFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
      @NotNull HttpServletRequest request,
      @NotNull HttpServletResponse response,
      @NotNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

      if (!request.isAsyncStarted()) {
      try {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        // It is set in the request processing flow.
        var id = BaggageField.getByName("id")
        System.out.println(id)
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
      }
    }
}
```

Can someone let me know when spring clears the trace context? I need to execute my filter before spring clears the baggage context?

- spring-boot version 3.0.12
- brave - 5.14.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave` ("Distributed Tracing" in the spring initializr), then this is happening in [`org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v6.1.3/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/ServerHttpObservationFilter.java), specifically the method `#createOrFetchObservation`:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("try")
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Observation observation = createOrFetchObservation(request, response);
    try (Observation.Scope scope = observation.openScope()) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        observation.error(unwrapServletException(ex));
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        throw ex;
    }
    finally {
        // Only stop Observation if async processing is done or has never been started.
        if (!request.isAsyncStarted()) {
            Throwable error = fetchException(request);
            if (error != null) {
                observation.error(error);
            }
            observation.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

The AutoConfiguration definition can be found in [`org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.observation.web.servlet.WebMvcObservationAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v3.2.2/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/observation/web/servlet/WebMvcObservationAutoConfiguration.java).

So you have to configure your custom filter to be run in the chain after the `ServerHttpObservationFilter` so that it is executed within the active Observation scope (The order value of the ServerHttpObservationFilter is `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE+1`).

If you are building a reactive web application, then you should be able to find a similar reactive filter.